# Change main content on sidebar item click using react-sidebar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: Screenshot of Panel]

I am using react-sidebar. Example demo code that I am using is live
[here](http://balloob.github.io/react-sidebar/example/responsive_example.html)

I dont want to reload page on sidebar item click. I just want to change main content text on sidebar-item click.

For example lets say i have have 3 menu items on sidebar : Mr.A, Mr.B, Mr.C

The main content on right side should say Hello, Mr.A or Hello, Mr.B or Hello, Mr.C accordingly. I just want to get data from sidebar to parent item which runs both sidebar as well as main content area. The source code of the above mentioned demo that I am using is [here](https://github.com/balloob/react-sidebar/tree/master/example/src)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to change the content based on what is clicked in the sidebar. You can use a routing solution [(more info)](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/):

1. react router(localhost:8080/mrA or localhost:8080/mrB) or
2. hash router (localhost:8080/#mrA or localhost:8080/#mrB)

another alternative is to use state to keep track of what option a user clicked in the sidebar and then display the appropriate content for that option [(conditional rendering based on state)](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#element-variables). In this linked example it uses an the if else pattern but you are not limited to that.